# passing object reference

Tags: c#

I have an object which contains other objects that it keeps up to date.
If I pass one of these sub-objects into the constructor of another class is this kept as a pointer and so identical to the object being updated?

In the below code stub I am using the EventDetails object. I do not need to modify this in the ResultsTreeViewEvent.

```
EventDetails eventDetails = raceDay.GetEvent(meeting, race);
ResultsTreeViewEvent newEvent = new ResultsTreeViewEvent(meet.name, eventDetails, ref treeView, fullPage, true);


public class ResultsTreeViewEvent
{
    public EventDetails race = null;

    public ResultsTreeViewEvent(String aMeetingName, EventDetails aRace, ref TreeView aTreeView, Boolean aFullPage, Boolean aShowMultiLegResults)
    {
        race = aRace;
    }
```

Comment: for this kind of questions it's really nice to build a few of your own classes and check out yourself. you always learn something interesting this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I pass one of these sub-objects into the constructor of another class is this kept as a pointer and so identical to the object being updated?

Well, it's kept as a *reference* - and if the object is updated via any of the references, those changes will indeed be visible via the other references, yes. You do *not* need to use `ref` for that. (It's not clear what you're trying to do with `aTreeView`, but you almost certainly don't want or need ref.)

References and pointers are very similar in some ways, but [aren't the same](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx). (C# *does* have pointers, in unsafe code, but you'll very rarely use them.)

See my articles on [reference and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) and [parameter passing in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have an issue where the object occasionaly did not seem to be updated and I needed to be sure of my assumptions. BTW the object is set as the treeview.TreeNode.Tag so I can check certain information while traversing the tree.

Comment: @BrianHewitson: I suspect you'll find that in those cases you were using a `struct` rather than a `class`. They behave differently, and you should understand both thoroughly. If you see any other peculiar bits of behaviour, you should extract them out of your program and ask about them with a short but complete example, in a separate question - I'm sure we'd be very happy to help you out.